# Parallel http get requests that get joined after all finish in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, nonblocking

I want to execute a number of http get requests in parallel, map over the results and then resynchronise (join) once all results are ready in order to render the resulting page.

Pseudocode:

```
var value_needed_to_render_page = async.parallel([array of values to iterate over], function to call in parralel on array).join()
return page_render(value_needed_to_render_page);
```

I've been looking at async and FutureJS, but didn't work out a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to do that is to use promises. `Q.all` will expect each of the functions in a list to return a promise, and will wait till all promises resolve. The following example is using q.js, https://github.com/kriskowal/q :

```
Q.all([
    functionToFireRequest1,
    functionToFireRequest2,
    // (...)
    functionToFireRequestN
]).then( function() { 
    doStuff(); 
});
```

`Q.all` receives a list of functions, so you can also generate the list programmatically.

As an example, the "functionToFireRequest" would look something like this:

```
function functionToFireRequest1() {
   var deferer = Q.defer();

   doMyRequestABCFoo( function() { deferer.resolve() } ); 
   // callback should be called inside your request after it finishes

   return deferer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Does then() return the array consisting results of all the calls? Or do I need to use something like express-promise middleware to be able to do rendering? Would I be able to render promises only in some of the handlers?

Comment: (In order) Yes, No, Yes

Comment: So the values that I need need to be passed as parameter to deferer.resolve? As in:

   doMyRequestABCFoo( function() { myCalculation; deferer.resolve(needed_value) } );

Comment: yup, that's the gist of it

Comment: It seems that _then_ passes the result to the callback parameter instead of returning the result. Does it sound true? Also _.then(function(x){return x;});_
doesn't return the computation result.

Comment: So it still leaves me without a way to render my page.

Comment: what are you using to render the page? If you are using express you can pass the res.render into the `then( function(results) { res.render( results);`